# Creating Test data for DataCloudcontact or DataCloudCompany in Apex Test Methods

Tags: data.com

I have a for loop iterating on a list of DataCloudCompany. From test methods, I could not query DatacloudCompany to fill the list nor can I create sample data to insert into the list. What options do I have.

```
for(DataCloudCompany dcc : lstdcc)
{
    Some Logic....
}
```

lstdcc needs to have some data and DataCloudCompany (part of Data.com API) could not be queried from test methods and data cannot be inserted either. Need guidance to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.datadotcom_api_dev_guide.meta/datadotcom_api_dev_guide/sforce_api_objects_datacloudcompany.htm):

> DatacloudCompany can’t be used in Apex test methods, because an
>   external web service call is required to access it. These calls are
>   not allowed in Apex test methods.

Thus, you have to make your class handle tests  to get code coverage. Kind of a pain - but I don't see a way around it.

I relied heavily on Test.isRunningTest() which is true during tests and had to create some dummy data to use when it is a test, via something like:

```
if(Test.isRunningTest()){ m = new Map<String, String>{ 'NaicsCode' => '000000' , 'ShippingCity' => 'Chicago', 'ShippingState' => 'IL' }; }
```

Where I fill this map with actual data when it isn't a test.

Also, I think coverage % is by lines, so if you combine multiple lines on the same line you can reduce the impact of the code sections the test misses:

`// instead of something like:
String a = 'a';
String b = 'b'; 
// do this to reduce impact of missed lines:
String a = 'a'; String b = 'b';`

Hope that helps!